# При наведении на картинку и текст прозрачность уменьшалась

Tags: html, css

Получилась анимация только при наведении на картинку. Как только курсор переходит на текст, анимация не срабатывает:(

```css
main .activity {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2050px;
  left: 31.5%;
  color: #fff;
  /*font-size: 30px;*/
  font-family: "Arial Regular" sans-serif;
}

main .activity .tlu {
  /*height: 50%;
 width: 50%;*/
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Arial Regular" sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  right: 62%;
}

main .activity .tlu p {
  position: relative;
  left: 15.6%;
  top: -207px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.tlu {
  height: 377px;
  width: 607px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tlu p:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.tlu img:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

main .activity .smr {
  height: 175px;
  width: 607px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Arial Regular" sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 160px;
  left: 43.1%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.smr img:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

main .activity .smr p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
  left: 8.9%;
  top: -100px;
  letter-spacing: 1.25px;
}

main .activity .ort {
  height: 175px;
  width: 607px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Arial Regular" sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
  left: 43.1%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ort img:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.ort:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

main .activity .ort p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  left: 13.9%;
  top: -120px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

main .bottom {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Arial Regular', sans-serif;
}

.b1 a {
  border: 1px solid #fecd39;
  padding: 15px 3%;
  background-color: #fecd39;
  color: #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 15.4%;
  position: relative;
  top: 205px;
  left: 18%;
  z-index: 25;
}

.b1 a:hover {
  background-color: #e2aa00;
  border-color: #e2aa00;
}

.b1 a:active {
  background-color: #e2aa00;
  border-color: #785a00;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 2px rgba(120, 90, 0, 0.5);
}

.b2 a {
  border: 1px solid #fecd39;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fecd39;
  padding: 15px 3%;
  color: #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 15.4%;
  position: relative;
  top: 247px;
  left: 65.5%;
  z-index: 25;
}

.b2 a:hover {
  background-color: #e2aa00;
  border-color: #e2aa00;
}

.b2 a:active {
  background-color: #e2aa00;
  border-color: #785a00;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 2px rgba(120, 90, 0, 0.5);
}

.b3 a {
  border: 1px solid #fecd39;
  padding: 15px 3%;
  background-color: #fecd39;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  left: 65.5%;
  z-index: 25;
}

.b3 a:hover {
  background-color: #e2aa00;
  border-color: #e2aa00;
}

.b3 a:active {
  background-color: #e2aa00;
  border-color: #785a00;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 2px rgba(120, 90, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="b1"><a href="transport.html">УЗНАТЬ БОЛЬШЕ</a></div>
  <div class="b2"><a href="trade.html">УЗНАТЬ БОЛЬШЕ</a></div>
  <div class="b3"><a href="stroyka.html">УЗНАТЬ БОЛЬШЕ</a></div>
</div>

<div class="activity">
  <h1>НАПРАВЛЕНИЯ ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ</h1>
  <div class="tlu"><img src="tlu.png">
    <p>ТРАНСПОРТ И ЛОГИСТИКА</p>
  </div>
  <div class="smr"><img src="smr.png">
    <p>СТРОИТЕЛЬНО-МОНТАЖНЫЕ РАБОТЫ</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ort"><img src="ort.png">
    <p>ОПТОВО-РОЗНИЧНАЯ ТОРГОВЛЯ</p>
  </div>

</div>
</main>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на картинку уменьшалась прозрачность и текста, и картинки, и фона текста ?

Comment: Из рубрики "Угадай вопрос сам".

Comment: Как сделать так,чтобы при наведении на картинку уменьшалась прозрачность и текста, и картинки, и фона текста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```css
.hover:hover img,
.hover:hover p {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover tlu">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
  <p>ТРАНСПОРТ И ЛОГИСТИКА</p>
</div>
<div class="hover smr">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
  <p>СТРОИТЕЛЬНО-МОНТАЖНЫЕ РАБОТЫ</p>
</div>
<div class="hover ort">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
  <p>ОПТОВО-РОЗНИЧНАЯ ТОРГОВЛЯ</p>
</div>
```